# Is there a way to use > operator in find -exec

Tags: find, exec

I'm trying to empty lots of files under a certain folder.

`>file` or `cat /dev/null > file` or `echo "" > file` can empty file. 
`find . -type f -exec blahblah {} \;` can find files and do something on them.

I tried to use the `>` operator in `find ... -exec` but the result is different to what I expected.

Is there a way to use `>` operator in the `find` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use it directly, since it will be interpreted as an actual redirection. You have to wrap the call in another shell:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'cat /dev/null >| $0' {} \;
```

If `sh` is Bash, you can also do:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '> $0' {} \;
```

Comment: Ouch! My head! How I can't remember that :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could redirect the output of the find command with [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do cat /dev/null > "$file"
done < <(find . type -f print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) allows escaping `>` as `\>`:

```
find . -type f|parallel \>{}
```

Or just use `read`:

```
find . -type f|while read f;do >"$f";done
```

You don't need `-r`, `-d ''`, or `IFS=` unless the paths contain backslashes or newlines or start or end with characters in `IFS`.

Comment: +1 for being a good solution. Probably not the one the OP was looking for, but very nice to have on the site.

Comment: :-( I just accidentally deleted a ton of work with this, for not reading carefully what this was about. I was just trying to figure out the `find` syntax with any command, so I could later change it to what I want. This `read` command doesn't look dangerous... but it is... shame on me, I'm scavenging for backups now...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one could just use the appropriately named `truncate` command.

Like this:

```
truncate -s 0 file.blob
```

The GNU coreutils version of `truncate` [also handles a lot of fascinating things](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate):

> SIZE may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters: '+' extend by, '-' reduce by, '<' at most, '>' at least, '/' round down to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of.

An even simpler, although less appropriately “named” method would be

```
cp /dev/null file.blob
```